# Escaping from inside the event horizon

Tags: black-holes, warp-drives

This is a hypothetical question.  An Alcubierre Warp Drive can theoretically go any speed because space is moving and the ship is not.  Could a ship equipped with this drive escape from inside an event horizon?  As I understand it, the space is not complete curved just inside the event horizon.  Is there anything that would keep said drive from functioning inside an event horizon?

Comment: Extreme time dilation would probably be an obstacle.